# Write data to GCP BigTable from external Hosting with .NET application

Tags: .net, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

We have a .NET application hosted in Rackspace. We'd like to write analytics data (simple logs) to BigTable, or any other product on the Google Cloud Platform from an external hosting.

1. Is it possible?
2. Is there any .NET library available for connecting and writing data to GCP BigTable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm the Cloud Bigtable client tech lead.  We are actively working on a C# client.  [Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet)'s the repository with all C# Google Cloud libraries, including our C# client that is in development.  [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Bigtable.V2/1.0.0-alpha02)'s the nugget.  We don't have any public docs yet, but we do have test code that could be used as examples.

We can work with you on priorities.  Please feel free to have a more in depth conversation on our [public discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-bigtable-discuss).  Once we have a general sense of your use case, we can potentially have more private discussions about how to fit your priorities into our ongoing development efforts.

FWIW, [this is my github profile](https://github.com/sduskis) with more contact info.

Warning: The Cloud Bigtable C# client is currently pre-alpha.

Comment: What about CloudSQL?

Comment: @Solomon we're also waiting for a C# client since we do most our application using .Net. For a starter, do you have a working samples on how to use the current pre-alpha C# client? Like how to query and load some data into bigtable? Thanks

Comment: Our initial example is here, which has a good start: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/pull/272. We are still working on performance and reliability features like automated retries

Answer (score 0):

[Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) (part of Google Cloud Platform) is designed exactly for collecting and analyzing logs, metrics, and uncaught exceptions, and more.  Your code can run anywhere and report to Stackdriver.  These C# samples show how to write your logs to stackdriver:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/logging/api

I haven't found a way to export to BigTable.  However, there are easy ways to export to Cloud Storage, Cloud Pub/Sub, or BigQuery.